# Ionic generate page error: Could not find your routes file

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm having trouble generating a new page in Ionic (Angular). Here's the command I used and the error I received:

```
$ ionic g page mypage
> ng generate page mypage --project=app
Could not find your routes file. Use the skip-import option to skip importing.
[ERROR] Could not generate page.
```

I've also tried using --skip-import but got an "Unknown argument" error. How can I resolve this to successfully generate a new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that my project is using `NgModules` but my Ionic CLI was somehow configured to use standalone components in `angular.json`.

I had to change `projects.app.schematics.@ionic/angular-toolkit:page.standalone` from `true` to `false`.  This resolved the issue.

Example:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
          "styleext": "scss",
          "standalone": false
        }
      },
...
```